# my query is causing mysqlid CPU to spike 99% usage, and i want to simplify the query

Tags: mysql, sql, deadlock

this is my **query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (game.game_id) 
AS gid, game_link.is_linked, game_link.game_id1, game_bet_settings.bet_type_id 
AS bet_type
FROM game
LEFT JOIN kiosk_to_game ON ( kiosk_to_game.game_id = game.game_id ) 
LEFT JOIN game_bet_settings ON ( game_bet_settings.game_id = game.game_id ) 
LEFT JOIN game_link ON ( game_link.game_id1 = game.game_id
OR game_link.game_id2 = game.game_id ) 
AND game.game_id !=  ''
AND game.game_winner =  '0'
AND game.game_open_bet_time <=  '2014-02-21 12:12:48'
AND game.game_close_bet_time >=  '2014-02-21 12:12:48'
AND kiyosuku_to_game.kiyosuku_id =  '1'
AND game.game_is_active =  '1'
AND game_bet_settings.is_disabled !=1
AND (game_link.is_linked IS NULL OR game_link.is_linked =1)
ORDER BY game.game_start_time ASC
```

i do think the culprit might be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (game.game_id) 
AS gid, game_link.is_linked, game_link.game_id1, game_bet_settings.bet_type_id 
AS bet_type
```

can anybody simplify this query to a much more efficient one?

here's an image for sql process:
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/--BsUDk8jLnY/UwbKFiCjZCI/AAAAAAAAAi4/MXCQFhs4PeU/w496-h216-no/sqlquery.png

here are some of my table indexes:

**game**

```
PRIMARY - game_id
```

**game_link**

```
PRIMARY - game_link_id   
game_id1 - game_id1, game_id2
```

**game_bet_settings**

```
PRIMARY - game_bet_settings_id
game_id - game_id
```

Comment: What do your indexes look like?

Comment: you want all table indexes? or just a specific one?

Comment: done editing the questions, hope it helps

Comment: Make sure you have also indexed `kiosk_to_game.game_id`. It's really hard to guess without seeing the data your working with. I'd suggest you try and simplify the query until you find which part causes the slowdown (e.g. try without the `order by`, try with only a single join and add the others back one at a time, etc). Order by performance can sometimes also [be improved by indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: thnx @CarlGroner, my query became 100x faster than my old one when i added an index to game_id

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding this index:

```
game(game_winner, is_active, open_bet_time, close_bet_time, game_id);
```

However, the culprit is probably:

```
LEFT JOIN game_link ON ( game_link.game_id1 = game.game_id OR game_link.game_id2 = game.game_id )
```

Queries with `or` are hard to optimize.

Try running your query without this condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (game.game_id) 
AS gid, game_link.is_linked, game_link.game_id1, game_bet_settings.bet_type_id 
AS bet_type
FROM game
LEFT JOIN kiosk_to_game ON ( kiosk_to_game.game_id = game.game_id ) 
LEFT JOIN game_bet_settings ON ( game_bet_settings.game_id = game.game_id ) 
LEFT JOIN game_link ON ( game_link.game_id1 = game.game_id ) 
AND game.game_id !=  ''
AND game.game_winner =  '0'
AND game.game_open_bet_time <=  '2014-02-21 12:12:48'
AND game.game_close_bet_time >=  '2014-02-21 12:12:48'
AND kiyosuku_to_game.kiyosuku_id =  '1'
AND game.game_is_active =  '1'
AND game_bet_settings.is_disabled !=1
AND (game_link.is_linked IS NULL OR game_link.is_linked =1)
ORDER BY game.game_start_time ASC
```

If this works in reasonable time, then try union'ing the two queries together (one with each condition).

EDIT:

The union would look like:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT (game.game_id) 
 AS gid, game_link.is_linked, game_link.game_id1, game_bet_settings.bet_type_id 
 AS bet_type
 FROM game
 LEFT JOIN kiosk_to_game ON ( kiosk_to_game.game_id = game.game_id ) 
 LEFT JOIN game_bet_settings ON ( game_bet_settings.game_id = game.game_id ) 
 LEFT JOIN game_link ON ( game_link.game_id1 = game.game_id ) 
 AND game.game_id !=  ''
 AND game.game_winner =  '0'
 AND game.game_open_bet_time <=  '2014-02-21 12:12:48'
 AND game.game_close_bet_time >=  '2014-02-21 12:12:48'
 AND kiyosuku_to_game.kiyosuku_id =  '1'
 AND game.game_is_active =  '1'
 AND game_bet_settings.is_disabled !=1
 AND (game_link.is_linked IS NULL OR game_link.is_linked =1)
)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT (game.game_id) 
 AS gid, game_link.is_linked, game_link.game_id1, game_bet_settings.bet_type_id 
 AS bet_type
 FROM game
 LEFT JOIN kiosk_to_game ON ( kiosk_to_game.game_id = game.game_id ) 
 LEFT JOIN game_bet_settings ON ( game_bet_settings.game_id = game.game_id ) 
 LEFT JOIN game_link ON ( game_link.game_id2 = game.game_id ) 
 AND game.game_id !=  ''
 AND game.game_winner =  '0'
 AND game.game_open_bet_time <=  '2014-02-21 12:12:48'
 AND game.game_close_bet_time >=  '2014-02-21 12:12:48'
 AND kiyosuku_to_game.kiyosuku_id =  '1'
 AND game.game_is_active =  '1'
 AND game_bet_settings.is_disabled !=1
 AND (game_link.is_linked IS NULL OR game_link.is_linked =1)
)
ORDER BY game_start_time ASC
```

Comment: tried and it still spiked. maybe some problem on the indexing

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to regroup a bit the query placing conditions to a subquery to restrict amount of records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (game.game_id) 
AS gid, game_link.is_linked, game_link.game_id1, game_bet_settings.bet_type_id 
AS bet_type
FROM (select * from game
      where
         game.game_id !=  ''
         AND game.game_winner =  '0'
         AND game.game_open_bet_time <=  '2014-02-21 12:12:48'
         AND game.game_close_bet_time >=  '2014-02-21 12:12:48'
         AND game.game_is_active =  '1'
     )
LEFT JOIN kiosk_to_game ON ( kiosk_to_game.game_id = game.game_id ) 
LEFT JOIN game_bet_settings ON ( game_bet_settings.game_id = game.game_id ) 
LEFT JOIN game_link ON ( game_link.game_id1 = game.game_id
OR game_link.game_id2 = game.game_id ) 
AND kiyosuku_to_game.kiyosuku_id =  '1'
AND (game_link.is_linked IS NULL OR game_link.is_linked =1)
ORDER BY game.game_start_time ASC
```

Comment: Every derived table must have its own alias